# javascript get / set for property/ values

Tags: javascript

why dose this log 3 twice ? and how should it be done?

so you can set a property like car.set('property', 'value')

and then return value by car.get('property')

for any value / property

```js
function Model() {}

Model.prototype = {
  get: function(property) {
    return this._value;
  },
  set: function(property, value) {
    this.property = value;
    this._value = value;
  }
};

var car = new Model();

car.set('name', 'ford');
car.set('age', 3);


console.log(
  car.get('name'),
  car.get('age')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use the dot syntax to set the properties, the property names will always be `"property"` and `"_value"`. So if you set multiple values, the last one will overwrite the previous one.

Instead, I think you wanted to set the property name to the value in the `property` variable. You can use the bracket syntax to achieve that.

```js
Model.prototype = {
  get: function(property){
      return this[property];
  },
  set: function (property, value){   
     this[property] = value;  
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Model` class only has one `_value` property that gets overridden once you set `age`.

You can instead store your property/value pairs in an object like such:

```
function Model() {
  this._storage = {};
}

Model.prototype.get = function(property) {
  return this._storage[property];
}

Model.prototype.set = function(property, value) {
  this._storage[property] = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be done this way:

```js
function Model() {}

Model.prototype = {
  get: function(property) {
    return this[property];
  },
  set: function(property, value) {
    this[property] = value;
  }
};

var car = new Model();

car.set('name', 'ford');
car.set('age', 3);


console.log(
  car.get('name'),
  car.get('age')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    Model.prototype = {
      data: {},
      get: function(property) {
          return this.data[property];
      },
      set: function (property, value) {   
         this.data[property] = value;
      }
    };
```